# Prolog Filtering List using `findall` with in-line predicate or "lambda"

Tags: syntax, prolog, swi-prolog

I have this data (the data is read from csv and it has to look like this, aka. a list of terms, rather than as plain terms defined in database):

```
Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
```

Now I wish to filter them by value, what I wish to do is like this (directly as query):

```
?- findall(Row, (member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50), Filtered).
```

However this won't work and gives:

```
?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], 
findall(Row, (member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50), Filtered). 
Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)],
Filtered = [_, _].
```

At the moment the only way to do it is to put them inside a file:

```
% Code.pl

% Have to provide this as a predicate
filter(Row, Rows) :-
    Row = row(_, Value),
    member(Row, Rows), 
    Value > 50.

% Also wanted to declare the following
% Neither works:
% data = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
% Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
```

Then I can do:

```
?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], findall(Row, filter(Row, data), Filtered).

# Or alternatively, wished to do:
?- findall(Row, filter(Row, data), Filtered).
```

On the other hand, while drafting this example I came across this problem:

```
% Wanted to put data directly inside code file, then query directly
% Neither works:
% data = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
% Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
```

I have two questions regarding syntax:

1. How to put the data directly inside the code file (for the purpose of this example), as a list of terms?
2. For the query, is there anyway to achieve what I wanted without having to put everything inside a script file? I.e. `Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], findall(Row, (member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50), Filtered).`

Remark:

- The title of this question looks like asking exactly what I am asking but not really: [Prolog, read a csv file and make a predicate. findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591030/prolog-read-a-csv-file-and-make-a-predicate-findall) and I don't know why their examples look so complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How to put the data directly inside the code file (for the purpose of this example), as a list of terms?

Either as a fact:

```
rows([row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)]).
```

then `rows(Rows)`, or as individual facts:

```
row('A', 150).
row('B', 300).
row('C', 50).
```

and then a findall to gather those up.

---

> 2. For the query, is there anyway to achieve what I wanted without having to put everything inside a script file?

Your findall line does not declare what `Row` is:

```
?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], 
   findall(Row, (member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50), Filtered). 
            ^
            |
            |_ this is an uninitialized variable,
               so your output is Filtered = [_, _] 
               a list of two unintialized variables.
```

so you could fix it as Paulo Moura answers, or you could do:

```
?-Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], 
  findall(row(Name, Value), (member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50), Filtered).

Filtered = [row('A',150), row('B',300)]
```

Or you could use `include/3` with a test predicate:

```
row_value_test(row(_, Value)) :-
    Value > 50.

?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], 
   include(row_value_test, Rows, Filtered).

Filtered = [row('A',150), row('B',300)]
```

or yes, you could do that inline with a lambda:

```
?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)], 
   include([row(_,V)]>>(V>50), Rows, Filtered).

Filtered = [row('A',150), row('B',300)]
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for auxiliary predicates or lambda expressions:

```
?- Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)],
   findall(Row, (member(Row,Rows), Row = row(Name, Value), Value > 50), Filtered).
Rows = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)],
Filtered = [row('A', 150), row('B', 300)].
```